# How to update view model from the view in Android

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I am using **Android Architecture Components** in my app. The use case I am dealing with is actually very simple.

Consider a simple Todo app where a todo-detail fragment is observing live data from a ViewModel holding an instance of currently open todo-item.

Since this fragment is in edit mode, it will let user edit properties of the item.

---

**Use Case 1**

There is an image button with Grey colored Flag icon in it. When user taps on it, the item is marked as 'High Priority' and changes color of flag to Red.

To achieve this, I am updating the property `viewModel.value.isHighPriority` to `true` on the view model instance which causes a change in data resulting in fragment listening to it. Fragment displays Flag color Red if `viewModel.value.isHighPriority = true`. So basically the UI event from view circles back to the view causing it to update.

**Use Case 2**

Consider a todo-item's title. It is shown in Android's `EditText`. In this case, how do I update view model with the data that user types in the box? I certainly do not want to highjack edit text's text changed events and handle character by character. That seems like an unnecessary hack to me.

---

This whole thing is making me rethink the way I am handling updates to view model's live data from view. If what I am doing (2-way data binding) is not a good practice, please suggest me how to handle a case where view receives UI events that causes updates to data that the view itself is presenting at the moment.

Comment: The use case 1 seems a legit case. That said, I feel LiveData shines the most when you are observing a data-source like SQLite database using Room.

That way if your data-source updates, it triggers LiveData which internally notifies it's observers which are usually in Activity or Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update your view model on basis of what user has typed, you have to have text watcher. even without a view model, there was no other way. If you have kept a button like submit, you can update your view model based on your onClick.

Actually, if you want the true essence of ViewModel you need to use it with conjunction to Databinding. Then you can directly call your view model's methods from your layout, and without the activity or fragment knowing most of it!

For example, in your case you could have called a method say `onPressed(Item item)` in your view model from your layout, and there you would have set the observable's priority value to Priority.HIGH. The layout would have changed automatically. The view needs to know nothing of this.

Even if you do not use data binding, consider in your first case if you had to make an api call on button press, and on success you had to update the view. Wouldn't that be messy without view model?